# Why do I get duplicated data.table rows after aggregation?

Tags: r, data.table

I aggregated a data.table by a column, and set that as a key, then was surprised to find that the table still contained duplicated rows.
What is the reason for this?

My table was special in that I had two columns with exactly the same values (but had to keep both for a practical reason), and I aggregated the table by one of those.

A simple example:

```
> library(data.table)
> dat = data.table(
+   class1 = c('a', 'a', 'b'), 
+   class2 = c('a', 'a', 'b'), 
+   value = 1:3)
> aggr = dat[, list(class2, sum(value)), keyby = class1]
> stopifnot(!any(duplicated(aggr)))
Error: !any(duplicated(aggr)) is not TRUE
```

Comment: You may need `dat[, list(unique(class2), sum(value)), keyby = class1]` or use `class1` and `class2` as grouping variables. `dat[, list(sum(value)), .(class1, class2)]`

Comment: Do `dat[, print(.SD), by=class1]` to understand what data is contained in each group. It's columns in this data.table that's extracted when you refer to variables on grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an aggregation function for all columns, then you get the expected result, without duplicated rows:

```
> library(data.table)
> dat = data.table(
+   class1 = c('a', 'a', 'b'), 
+   class2 = c('a', 'a', 'b'), 
+   value = 1:3)
> aggr = dat[, list(class2[[1]], sum(value)), keyby = class1]
> stopifnot(!any(duplicated(aggr)))
```

Note that the difference is that I take the first element of the `class2` column. Note that any other function that outputs one value works as well.

Comment: A warning would not make sense. `by=` is not simply for aggregation, and your example (having two identical columns for ... reasons unknown) doesn't do much to convince me that there are real cases where a warning would be useful.

Comment: @Frank A better example instead of two identical columns would be where class1 further characterizes class2; so class2 would be the same for each class1 value. Nevertheless my request for a warning is not valid: Originally I thought that keyby was for aggregating the data.table. I just read the documentation more thoroughly, and now I realize it is more general than that. Thanks for explaining that! I am removing my comment saying that there should be a warning when this happens.